# Robot Loud Alarm

Tags: microcontroller, ros, navigation

We are working on a project where we want to sound an alarm if somebody is messing around with our Robot (e.g., the Robot is being shaken abruptly or the cameras/LIDARs are blocked).
I am using "loud speakers" (4.1 x 3 inch 10 Watts 8 ohm speakers), but they are not loud enough.

Are there any small speakers or alarm systems small enough, but loud enough (closed to a car alarm) that you would recommend? 
Ideally something that I can just plug into the robots computer, or interface with through a microcontroller. Either one would be fine.

Comment: The answer to this will depend on size, power supply and required volume.  Presumably you can't just add an audio amplifier between your existing alarm generator and the speaker?

Comment: Currently I have a Boss audio amplifier for the speakers. I have 4 speakers (with the specs mentioned about) and they are getting full power at 12V. We are using an overspeced 26V battery that supplies more than enough power for all devices. I want something can be heard 100-300 meters away or scare/throw someone on the ground because of the noise, yet something that I can send signals to with a computer and/or MCU. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Can you explain why simply using a car alarm siren would not work for you?

Comment: A car alarm siren would definitely work. Any that you recommend?

Comment: If you just want to make really load noise, 
there are signal horns usually used in football stadiums with something around 135dB powered by 12V
This systems use a compressor and are not speakers anymore....
for example this one here on ebay:
[here on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Super-Loud-12v-Dual-Trumpet-Air-Horn-Compressor-Kit-Train-Car-Truck-Boat-135db-/111446506739?pt=Car_Speakers&hash=item19f2babcf3)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a hacky solution then opening one of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003DWH4KG) might be the best way to go. Just replace the button with a FET (or standard transistor) and be on your way. 
If you wan't a more traditional/better looking solution, then the best thing I can recommend is getting a larger speaker/amplifier. It looks like one can buy car horns, but that would probably take more wiring than necessary. 
If I were in your position, I would go with the electronic whistle.